# Reactjs Rest API response decode JSON

Tags: reactjs, json

I am getting a rest API response from a API URL. But I need to decode some parts of response from JSON to Object.Here is the Response.

[image]

Here you can see `price` and `service_timespan` this two things needs to be in JSON.parse(). So that this values can be used.Other wise, I cannot use them.

here is my code

```
{ services.length > 0 && services.map(( service, index ) => (
<tr key={service.id} className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'bg-white' : 'bg-gray-50'}>
    <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">{service.service_name}</td>
    <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">{service.service_cat_id}</td>
    <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">{service.price.base_price.amount}</td>
    <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">{service.service_timespan.duration.length}</td>
    <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
    <a href="#" className="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">
        Edit
    </a>
    </td>
</tr>
))
}
```

Here I am getting `cannot read property amount of undefined`

Comment: You seem to be aware of `JSON.parse` to parse JSON, so what is stopping you from doing so?

Comment: I think what's tripping you up is that you're receiving a JSON string that includes fields whose values are also json strings. So after parsing the outer object those values are still strings that need to be `JSON.parse`d separately.

Comment: @rayhatfield Exactly you are correct. When i am using map function I also need to JSON.parse those json strings also. But I cannot get it

Answer (score 0):

```
{ (services || []).map(s => {
    ...s, 
    price: JSON.parse(s.price),
    service_timestamp: JSON.encode(s.service_timestamp)
  })
   .map(( service, index ) => ( your component) }
```

But if you can, avoid to put this inside your component since this will be evaluated on each render. Do the parse thing in the Api service if you have, when you get the response or in a `useMemo`